# SDL program crash on close - c0000005?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

trying to just make a simple program to display the picture loaded into the system. If I type in an image name not found in the directory it returns and error to say it hasn't been found, but for some reason after this when I return 0; inside the main I get a crash.

I cannot find a way to solve it. Any help for what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include "SDL_Wrapper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Image {
public:
    Image();
    ~Image();
    int loadImage();
    int saveImage();
    int outputImage();
protected:
    int height, width;
    string imageName;
    SDL_Surface* displayWindow;
    SDL_Surface* imageSurface;
    SDL_Surface* tempSurface;
};

Image::Image() {
    displayWindow = NULL;
    imageSurface = NULL;
    tempSurface = NULL;
}

Image::~Image() {
}

int Image::saveImage() {
    return 0;
}

int Image::outputImage() {
    return 0;
}

int Image::loadImage() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1) {
        cout << "Error: Did not initialise correctly" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter the image name (and extension) you wish to use - ";
    cin >> imageName;
    imageSurface = LoadImage(imageName.c_str());

    // Check if the image has been loaded correctly
    if (imageSurface == NULL) {
        imageSurface = NULL;
        SDL_Quit();
        cout << "Error: Picture not loaded/found" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    displayWindow = SDL_SetVideoMode(imageSurface->w, imageSurface->h, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    if (displayWindow == NULL) {
        cout << "Error: displayWindow is blank, halting";
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Image Preview", NULL);
    SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, displayWindow, NULL);
    if (SDL_Flip(displayWindow) == -1) {
        cout << "Error: displayWindow did not flip correctly";
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while (quit == false) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(imageSurface);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

void test()
{
    Image img;
    img.loadImage();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Compiler tells me this -

```
Unhandled exception at 0x776015de in SDL_Display.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x61d47bce.
```

In the 'Call Stack' it is on the line

```
- > SDL_Display.exe!std::_DebugHeapDelete<std::locale::facet>(std::locale::facet * _Ptr)  Line 62 + 0xc bytes   C++
```

Edit 2: LoadImage() function -

```
// Load Image
SDL_Surface* LoadImage(const char* ImageLocation)
{
    // Initialize Variables
    SDL_Surface *SDL_S_Return = NULL;

    // Load Image
    SDL_S_Return = IMG_Load(ImageLocation);

    // If it hasn't been loaded...
    if(SDL_S_Return == NULL)
    {
        // Send out an Error Message
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    }

    // Return the Surface (Will be NULL if file isn't loaded)
    return SDL_S_Return;
}
```

Comment: Does it crash immediatly after the return statement? Use a debugger to  get the exact line it crashes at.

Comment: What does your debugger say as to where the access violation gets triggered in your code?

Comment: There you go, I think I've given you guys the right information.

Comment: Can you give us the implementation of `LoadImage()`?

Comment: Edited into the main post

Comment: You should be using the "@username" notation when replying in comments, otherwise people don't know that you've made a reply. I only saw it because I came back here manually. Anyway, I can't see anything wrong with the code. I even built it here and ran it (GCC 4.7.2, SDL 1.2.15, SDL_image 1.2.12) and there are no errors.

Comment: @NikosC. sorry about not using the @ reply, didn't even notice there was such a thing, haven't asked on here in a while. Well that is very odd. I guess there is just something wrong with my machine, as if I try and blit and image to a window and leave it there to do other things in the console the window crashes (I guess this shouldn't happen). I think Visual Studio is my issue then, or something else is causing it.

Comment: @NikosC. turns out the issue is with the `string imageName`, if I take any string inside the protected section and take input with cin>> it causes the error when returning 0 in the main

Answer (score 0):

your code is OK. it runs well and the only problem I can see is:
you did not convert loaded image to display format.
try this function:

```
 SDL_Surface *loadImage(char *imageToLoad)
{
    SDL_Surface *rawImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *fixedImage = NULL;

    //load image from file
    rawImage = IMG_Load(imageToLoad);
    //fix image's depth
    fixedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(rawImage);
    //transparenty
    Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(fixedImage->format,0xff,0,0);
    SDL_SetColorKey(fixedImage,SDL_SRCCOLORKEY,colorkey);
    //free memory
    SDL_FreeSurface(rawImage);
    return fixedImage;
}
```